# Fill empty cell and rename column name of the multi-index header from excel file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a excel file with the following format:

[image]

Reading with: `df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1], index_col=[0])`

Out:

```
         2018           2019      
name quantity price quantity price
bj         10     2        6     5
sh          7     2        3     2
```

I want to manipulate the multi-index headers by filling the empty cell with `year` and rename `name` as `city`.

How could I do that in Pandas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(columns=['year','city'])
```

If possible there is index name and necessary remove, set to `None`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(columns=['year','city'], index=None)
```

Comment: Sorry, it works for one file, but when I iterate multiple files under a folder, it raises `KeyError: "['quantity'] not in index"`, any ideas? Maybe some files' headers are not same as others?

Comment: @ahbon - Unfortuantely you are right, there is different format.

Comment: That's correct, I have found the file with different header. :)